# New version of libc on Debian

Tags: atom-editor

I want to use the atom.io text editor but it doesn't like my glibc version. Is it safe to do the steps performed in this article? http://axiacore.com/blog/atom-editor-debian/

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  Doing that will force you to track [Debian testing](https://www.debian.org/releases/testing/), which (depending on what [release](https://www.debian.org/News/2015/20150426) you have installed) can give a large number of updates initially, and a continuing stream of frequent updates.

I use several virtual machines including Debian testing, and occasionally have to reinstall the testing machines.  For instance, tracking Debian testing over the past couple of years, I had a machine that required reinstalling the kernel about twice a month and finally did not boot at all.

Others may reflect different experience.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing is to download the source code of the `glibc` version you require, and compile your code against this version, using also the **-static** linker option, which embeds the routine code inside the executable, so that  your system's glibc is not called, and there is no conflict.

If you run into problems, then first at least you have not compromised your system. Second, you can probably solve them by looking up [this Web page](http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=103), which teaches you how to link against older versioned symbols.